# Are there unsafe characters in PDF custom property values?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

In an application, I am allowing (potentially untrusted) users to store an arbitrary string (limited to 255 characters) in the value of a PDF custom property.

Are there any unsafe characters that can lead to an exploit?

Comment: Not pet se. But there always is a chance some character sequences trigger bugs in some pdf viewers, in particular exotic, less tested ones.

Comment: @mkl Mind to make this an Answer so I can accept it? Thanks

Comment: *"Mind to make this an Answer so I can accept it?"* - Here you are, you're welcome.

Comment: Thanks! I have just accepted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there any unsafe characters that can lead to an exploit?

Not per se.

Every PDF viewer implementation should get along with 255 arbitrary valid characters, and I'm not aware of any specific exploits.

But of course there *always* is a chance some character sequences trigger bugs in some pdf viewers, in particular in exotic, less tested ones.